# Coffeescript parentheses for function invocation

Tags: javascript, syntax, coffeescript

Coffeescript gives the freedom to set or omit parentheses for functions calls. Like

```
alert 'Hi folks'
alert ('Hi folks')
```

are equal.

Now I am wondering, probably due to insufficient experience with coffeescript, its syntax and its aim to keep things simple, if it possible to add parentheses for a statement like the following. *I know they aren't necessary*.

```
define (require) ->
   return 'goodbye'
```

Edit: If I apply the option to set parentheses in the same manner as for the alert statement, than I would assume this syntax shouldn't make any difference to the final js.

```
define ((require) ->
   return 'goodbye'
)
```

Comment: Can you add the last statement with parentheses added the way you want to? I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
define (require) ->
   return 'goodbye'
```

would be equivalent to the JavaScript code

```
define(function(require) { return 'goodbye' })
```

That is, a function call to `define` with a function as its first (and only) argument. It is probably not what you expected the snippet to do when you asked your question.

Something I found very helpful when I played around with CoffeeScript was to try things out in the on-line "try CoffeeScript" dialogue on [the CoffeeScript website](http://coffeescript.org). This allows you to see the JavaScript that a given snippet is compiled to, and immediately see what effect e.g. adding parentheses or changing indentation has on the resulting JavaScript code. I definitely recommend doing that. :-)

**Edit** to reflect the edit in the question:

Yes, adding parentheses around the function (`(require) -> return 'goodbye'`) is valid, and doesn't alter the behaviour. Note however that "`foo (bar)`" and "`foo(bar)`" is parsed differently by the parser; in the former the parenthes denote precedence (priority, "regular parentheses"), and in the latter they are function invocation parentheses.

"`foo bar`", "`foo(bar)`", "`foo (bar)`" all do the same thing, but whereas "`foo bar, baz`" and "`foo(bar, baz)`" work fine, "`foo (bar, baz)`" is a syntax error.

Comment: Thx. Actually this is what I am looking for. I am simply curious, if its possible to wrap the anonymous function as if it were a simple parameter.

Comment: Thx for your update + the additional info. So to summarize, in cases like the one above the parentheses do have an impact on the final output: `define((function(require) { return 'goodbye'; }));`. Whereas with a simple parameter - like in the alert - they don't?

Comment: @SunnyRed: They have as much of an impact with alert as with define. It's just that it's "prioity parentheses", and not "function call parentheses". If there's no whitespace between the function and the left parenthesis, then it's interpreted as part of the function call syntax.

Comment: Functionality wise. I know it's quite a non-issue, but the compiled js is different, with extra parentheses in the "advanced" case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can wrap an anonymous function in parentheses.

I ran this simple script.

test.coffee

```
define = (func) -> func()

console.log define ((require) ->
   return 'goodbye'
)
```

output:

```
goodbye
```